# How do I open an html file in an html file in the same widow in js

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a main html file [index.html] and I have a second html file and so in the main one I have a text box and then a search button when you type America it should bring up the other html file but i don't know how to do it so it opens in the same widow, and I can't use href bc I'm trying to use the file

```js
function myFunction() {
  var inputCoun = document.getElementById("country").value;

  if (inputCoun == "") {
    alert("You need to type something first");
    submitOK = "false";
  }
  if (inputCoun == "America") {
    window.open("https://www.w3schools.com", "replace", "_top")
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return myFunction()">
  <input type="text" id="country" size="20" name="country"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Sounds like Single Page App work. Usually you get response from server via Ajax, then put dynamic HTML from it

Comment: _“and I can't use href bc I'm trying to use the file”_ - no idea what you even mean by that.

Comment: like I want to use the html file not a link

Comment: Generally speaking the best approach would be to create a SPA, lots of frameworks out there that do this.   But based on your description, HTML inside HTML, this is called an `<IFrame/>`, personally I would avoid this though, as it adds complexity to the rendering especially on mobile devices.

Comment: well not like html inside a html but like it replaces the HTML with a new html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some choices.

I would do

```
this.action = "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/";
```

but that does not work here at SO so I use

```
location.replace("https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/");
```

Complete code:

Note: I gave the form an ID
Also I wrap in a load EventListener to make sure the elements are on the page at script time

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var inputCoun = document.getElementById("country").value;

    if (inputCoun == "") {
      alert("You need to type something first");
      return false
    }

    if (inputCoun == "America") {
      location.replace("https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm" target="_top">
  <input type="text" id="country" size="20" name="country"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

If you want America.html, do

```
location.replace(inputCoun+".html");
```

or

```
this.action = inputCoun+".html";
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at /script.js:1:34

it send an error

Comment: @Tomorrow please read just the first line of the provided code `document.getElementById("myForm")` - Make sure you have such ID on your form.

Comment: sorry I'm trying but yeah I have that id

Answer (score 0):

use

```js
window.location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com"
```

or

```js
window.location.href="./2.html"
```

Comment: ahh so like I have an html file America.html and so if I want to publish it I think it would be better with out the href

Comment: `window.location.href="./America.html"` @Tomorrow